# Can't get D3 zoom working with openstreetmap in React?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, openstreetmap

Been stuck on this for a while, tricky stuff! So I've been trying to get D3 map tiles working, and so far I've figured out how to add a projection, and then use a topojson file to add countries, us states, zip codes etc. I would like to have d3 call on the openstreetmap database to get a more detailed, open source map with streets and other topographical features. I made a similar post a couple of weeks ago with a terrifying wall of code - no replies!

Since I feel that I've narrowed down the issue to the D3 zoom plugin, here's a modified post. I am able to get openstreetmap...but you see the entire world as one 256x256 map tile, so it's tiny! I think until this zoom is working you only get the one small map tile? Any ideas?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ktjlxk?embed=1&file=index.js

The link above shows what I have so far. I am trying to plugin this map from Mike Bostock into react: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797 ...my version of zooming with D3 is borrowed from a post by the intrepid Swizec Teller: https://swizec.com/blog/two-ways-build-zoomable-dataviz-component-d3-zoom-react/swizec/7753

In case it helps, you can see a few different versions of the packages I am using from the package.json file:

"d3-geo": "^1.11.3",
"d3-geo-projection": "^2.6.0",
"d3-tile": "0.0.4",
"d3-zoom": "^1.7.3",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",

I would appreciate any help or suggestions!

Comment: D3-tile isn't particularly intuitive and appears to be causing some trouble for you. Is there a particular reason why you want to have the images displayed within a div rather than an svg?

Comment: Agreed an svg would be better, but wasn't getting anything? I think I had it working previously by putting the image into a <g> or an <svg>...but after trying a bunch of stuff that broke my code, using a div with an #id got the image to show up for this version. Certainly not attached to doing it that way!